# Searching only for white spaces in a String in Flex

Tags: string, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

```
  var sample:String = filterBox.text;
```

Based on the String I get from TextInput, a Button has to be disabled if the String has only white spaces and enabled only otherwise.

I want to check if the String has only white spaces.

Is/Are there any inbuilt methods in flex for this? I saw some answers for Java to use trim method. But its not available in Flex. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

StringUtil.trim(string);

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/StringUtil.html

String has a lot of methods which match for patterns you can find it here. 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
private const r:RegExp = /\S/;

private function isEmpty(str:String):Boolean {
    return = !r.test(str);
}
```

then

```
trace(isEmpty("hello world")); //false
trace(isEmpty("  ")); //true
trace(isEmpty(" ")); //true
```

Comment: +1; but overkill for just testing for spaces. A simple Trim() as in Zeus answer seems like an "Easier" approach.

Comment: Thanks. But trim() was much easier. I will save this up for later.